# Proof of formula for the arc length

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, arc-length

I've read the proof of formula for arc length . I wonder why the function has to have continuous derivative (According to the Stewart Calculus book). I mean in which part of the proof we used this assumption ? Here is the proof : https://brilliant.org/wiki/arc-length/

Comment: I do not see where the theroem you link to presupposes continuity of the derivative: " Given a function that is defined and differentiable on the interval ..." - Of coourse, they implicitly assume that $\int\sqrt{1+f'(t)^2}\,\mathrm dt$ exists

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes but In the Stewart's book is written : "The definition of arc length given by Equation 1 is not very convenient for computational purposes, but we can derive an integral formula for $L$ in the case where $f$ has a continuous derivative. [Such a function $f$ is called smooth because a small change in x produces a small change in $f'(x)$.]

Answer (score 3):

It is assumed so that the expression $\sqrt{1 + \left( \dfrac {dy}{dx} \right)^2}$ is Riemann integrable and the approximating Riemann sums converge to the right thing.

Comment: What would happen if $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not continuous ?

Comment: I would guess things would be fine if $dy/dx$ were merely Riemann integrable.

Comment: @zhw. Yes , I agree with you .